# Error 404 when reading properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to read data from properties file.I have specified the path in xml.When I run the app it throws an error -

***org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'fbStuffKeeper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'facebook.appId'**

My applicationContext.xml -

```
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cognizant.awcoe.bazaar.social.spring.controllers" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
             <property name="location" value="classpath:/com/social/spring/config/facebook.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="fbStuffKeeper" class="com.social.spring.facebook.FBStuffManager">
        <property name="secret" value="${facebook.appSecret}"/>
        <property name="clientId" value="${facebook.appId}"/>
        <property name="redirectURI" value="${redirect.uri}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

facebook.properties contain-

```
facebook.appID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
facebook.appSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
redirect.uri=http:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Have I specified the path of the properties file correctly..Where did I go wrong??
Kindly correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a mistaken case of the last `d`: `facebook.appId` instead of `facebook.appID`

Comment: Yea!!It certainly removed the error but still 404 error pops up...I am not getting any error but I see No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSocial/login.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringSocial'